# Incorrect MIDI note length

Tags: c#, midi

I am trying to write a MIDI file in C#. I am using Sanford MIDI Toolkit. The following is a code snippet I am using to write `NoteOn` and `NoteOff` events.

```
private static void InsertNoteOn(Track t, int pitch, int velocity, int position, int duration, int channel)
{
    ChannelMessageBuilder builder = new ChannelMessageBuilder();
    builder.Command = ChannelCommand.NoteOn;
    builder.Data1 = pitch;
    builder.Data2 = velocity;
    builder.MidiChannel = channel;
    builder.Build();
    t.Insert(position, builder.Result);
}

private static void InsertNoteOff(Track t, int pitch, int velocity, int position, int duration, int channel)
{
    ChannelMessageBuilder builder = new ChannelMessageBuilder();
    builder.Command = ChannelCommand.NoteOff;
    builder.Data1 = pitch;
    builder.Data2 = velocity;
    builder.MidiChannel = channel;
    builder.Build();
    t.Insert((position + duration), builder.Result);
}
```

First I insert all `NoteOn` events for all notes of the track, then I insert all `NoteOff` events of the track.

The approach works most of the time. However, sometimes the resulting MIDI file is rendered incorrectly. The problem happens sometimes when two notes of the same pitch are written after one another. The first note will render with its length equaling to both notes' lengths, and the second note will have length zero.

My assumption is that the `NoteOff` event of the first note is interpreted as `NoteOff` of the second note and vice versa.

I have tried the following variations:

1. Add each individual note with its `NoteOn` and `NoteOff` events in the temporal order in the track

   1. If notes have the same position, top pitch to bottom pitch
   2. If notes have the same position, bottom pitch to top pitch
2. Add all `NoteOn` events in temporal order and then add all `NoteOff` events in temporal order
3. Add all `NoteOff` events in temporal order and then add all `NoteOn` events in temporal order
4. Reduce the length of all notes by the smallest possible amount

Only the last approach works, but notes have shorter length, which does not fix the problem.

Is there a fix to this? Is there a specific order which `NoteOn` and `NoteOff` events should take in the track? Is there a specific order in which the track insertion method should be called?

**EDIT:** The problem occurs in the following case:
[image: FL Studio screenshot]

The higher note was moved from C to C# for visibility. These were supposed to be two notes of the same length, but instead one was rendered with both notes' lengths and the other has zero length.

Comment: Good odds you'll trip a bug in the library by not adding the messages in temporal order.  Just sort them yourself first.

Comment: I tried that, and it still fails. Is there a defined order in which they should be sorted? The problem happens with messages that occur at the same point in time.

Comment: What you mean by rendered incorrectly? With a midi file, the order of events either note on or off is not a problem, but the playback will of course affected like a note plays for ever. (Or till to the next note off event for the same not may be measures later)

Comment: The file is not written correctly. When I open it in a DAW (FL Studio), the notes are not displayed correctly.

Comment: Definitely a bug with this library. I don't know the library, but it is just not good encapsulation there to get the command's data with data 1 and data 2 attributes.

Comment: You know, with no instrument can you play a note without muting it first, only digital representation of music allows you to do that. Can you just avoid that?

Comment: @OguzOzgul: Actually, I don't think it's the library, because I am passing manually coded MIDI events in real-time to a VSTi and a similar thing happens (it is noticeable in the audio).

Comment: so the problem is on1 - - on2 - - off2 - - off1. And the behavior is well by design. Note 1 will play till off2. This is pressing a piano key and pressing it again without releasing it which is not possible.

Comment: am I missing something else? When two note on events do not overlap, do you still have this problem? I think not (your workaround 3. works)

Comment: The problem is that on1-off1-on2-off2 is written and interpreted as on1-on2-off2-on1. I edited the question and added a screenshot.

Comment: oh my. But then, you should provide your on and off events in the exact order, because the software cannot determine the desired order of events occurring at the same time stamp

Comment: I am also wondering why you are first inserting all the note on events because this is not the natural happening order of events. Is there a special reason for that?

Comment: First time seeing a midi related question on SO by the way, liked it. +1

Comment: I have the same problem in node.js too.

I test `on1`-- `off1` -- `on2` -- `off2`

but this is not working correctly and `on2` works after the `off1` time.

after that, I test `on1` -- `on2` -- `off1` -- `off2`
  in this case, on1 time is half of on2.


Does anyone have the solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by sorting all the events before inserting them into the track. I used the following method.

```
private static void InsertNote(int pitch, int velocity, int position, int duration, int channel, ref List<Tuple<int, bool, ChannelMessage>> messages)
{
    ChannelMessageBuilder builder = new ChannelMessageBuilder();
    builder.Command = ChannelCommand.NoteOn;
    builder.Data1 = pitch;
    builder.Data2 = velocity;
    builder.MidiChannel = channel;
    builder.Build();
    messages.Add(new Tuple<int, bool, ChannelMessage>(position, true, builder.Result));
    builder.Command = ChannelCommand.NoteOff;
    builder.Data1 = pitch;
    builder.Data2 = velocity;
    builder.MidiChannel = channel;
    builder.Build();
    messages.Add(new Tuple<int, bool, ChannelMessage>(position + duration, false, builder.Result));
}
```

The method was used in the following way.

```
List<Tuple<int, bool, ChannelMessage>> messages = new List<Tuple<int, bool, ChannelMessage>>();
foreach (var n in track.Notes)
    InsertNote(n.Pitch, n.Velocity, (int)(n.Position * LENGTH_MULTIPLIER), (int)(n.Length * LENGTH_MULTIPLIER), 0, ref messages);
messages = messages.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item2).ToList();
foreach (var x in messages)
    t.Insert(x.Item1, x.Item3);
```

Comment: Can you explain more about that and your solution?
I have the same issue in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

In MIDI files, it is possible for multiple events to have the same timestamp. In this case, they are sent over the wire in the same order as they are written in the file.

The Sanford MIDI toolkit uses only the timestamp to specify an event's position, and does not document how multiple events with the same timestamp are handled.

To ensure that your note-off events come before the note-on events, you have to use different timestamps, i.e., reduce the length of the notes. (To lower the actual difference, increase the timestamp resolution.)

Comment: What he tries to accomplish is actually very sensible. Off the note and On it again at the same instant. The problem lies in the way he inserts the events, all note on events first, then all the off events, and in that case, at the same time stamp, the note on comes first. He should be able to achieve this without altering the note lengths

Comment: @OguzOzgul There is no guarantee that events with the same timestamp have the same ordering as they're inserted. In fact, the Sanford MIDI toolkit uses insertion sort.